# SVG test on IE and FF

Tags: internet-explorer, firefox, svg, internet-explorer-10

While I was learning the SVG filters, I came across a confusing scenario.

In FF16 and IE9/IE10-RTM open the following SVG document:

http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/images/SVG_TESTS/svg_test.svg

You will notice that the triangles, squares and circles are opaque/filled in Firefox but IE renders them transparent (you can see through the black curve).

[image: Firefox preview]
[image: IE Preview]

Firefox                       Internet Explorer

According to W3C recommendations, which browser is showing the correct behavior?

Comment: It's unclear what you mean, there are lots of shapes in that example.

Comment: @ErikDahlström, check the edits. I have added the images for clarification. I just want to learn which behavior is correct. Please consider reversing the "closed as off topic" decision.

Comment: Looks like a bug in IE, seems like IE inherits fill-opacity into the markers. You should probably bugreport it.

Comment: @ErikDahlström, I have found a reference on [W3C.org](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/painting.html#FillOpacityProperty) and one on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ff972258%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Apparently, the fill-opacity must inherit the value from its parent unless specified. Is it relevant?

Comment: Since the markers aren't children of the path that has fill-opacity set the markers shouldn't inherit that property.

Comment: There are a number of SVG marker issues open in the [IE 10 issue list](https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/SearchResults.aspx?SearchQuery=svg%2520marker) (requires a microsoft account to see, stupidly). I've added information about a similar one I saw, and I'd recommend you do the same, or at least click on the "me too!" links, since the folks that IE hires to filter the issues (I assume non-developers) seem to reject lots of them.